# How to setup KVO on a Collection (NSArray or NSSet) of NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, key-value-observing

I have an iPad app that has a `UITableViewController` that implements the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`. (Mostly using the `CoreDataTableViewController` [code](http://www.timroadley.com/Tutorials/CoreDataBasicsPart2/CoreDataTableViewController.zip)  from the Stanford iOS classes.)

I have a secondary model object (`self.locations`) that is an array of `Location` objects which is a subclass of `NSManagedObjects`. This array drives the content of a `UISegmentedControl` that filters my main `fetchedResultsContoller`.

It is possible to modify the contents of `self.locations` via a popover. I want to set up some sort of observing so that my main `UITableViewController` can watch for changes in the objects stored in `self.locations` and reload the `UISegmentedControl` if necessary.

This might also result in a reload of the main data in the table, so I want to be careful to not reload on every little modification.

I think I understand how to setup KVO on a single `NSManagedObject` but I'm not sure how to do it on object contained in an array. I understand that I can use another NSFetchedResultsController, but my `self.locations` object does not drive a second UITableView, so I'm not sure it makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is pretty straight-forward to observe a one-to-many relationship if all you want to know if  objects are added, removed, replaced, or re-ordered.  In fact, it is done exactly the same way as with a normal object:

```
[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"locations"
          options:0
          context:NULL];
```

Then implement the following to receive notifications (partially copied from Apple docs):

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"locations"]) {
        // Your custom code here.
    }

    // Be sure to call the superclass's implementation *if it implements it*.
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                         ofObject:object
                           change:change
                           context:context];
}
```

Don't forget to stop observing at some point:

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"locations"];
```

And, although you didn't ask, if you want to know if any of the **objects** contained in the relationship have **changed** (and not just the NSSet that you are watching here) then you have to observe the individual objects.

**EDIT**

Per your comment, you do want to observe the individual objects.  This is fairly straight-forward for "normal" objects, but a managed object takes a bit more work because you have to observe the individual keys in the object, which would look something like this:

```
- (void)observeManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)myObject {
    NSArray *myObjectKeys = [[[myObject entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
    for (NSString *key in myObjectKeys) {
        [myObject addObserver:self 
                    forKeyPath:key 
                       options:0 
                       context:nil];
    }
}
```

And then you observe all of the NSManagedObjects in the array like this:

```
for (NSManagedObject *object in myArray) {
    [self observeManagedObject:object];
}
```

Do the reverse to stop observing the keys on the managed object!